# What are the problems that can arise in an implementation that lacks polymorphism?

Tags: polymorphism

I understand what polymorphism means but I'm having difficulty understanding the problems that arise if it isn't used. Could someone explain it to me?

Comment: Code Duplication pops to mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic concept is code re-use. Polymorphism is achieved in .NET via interfaces and abstract/base classes. Say you have a `Cat` class that has a `Speak()` method which outputs "MEOW!" and say that you use this class all over your application as type `Cat`. Now, if one day you need to replace all cats with Dogs using a `Dog` class who has a `Speak()` method which outputs "WOOF!" you're going to have a lot of manual work to do to replace all instances of `Cat` with `Dog`. And what if you need a method that can let a `Cat` or `Dog` speak? Then you need a lot of copy-paste boiler-plate redundant code.

Imagine instead that you code `Cat : ISpeak` and `Dog : ISpeak` where `ISpeak` is an interface which exposes the `Speak()` method. Now you have no rework to do at all and can happily switch between `Cat`, `Dog`, and other things that can speak, as long as you use the interface type for all type declarations.